# What could be the reasons for two different OTP messages for the same merchant when we do online transactions through debit card?

Tags: one-time-password

While I was doing a transaction (say adding money to one of the mobile wallets) through a SBI debit card, I could see two different OTP messages for different transactions. (Please refer to the image)

Say one time I am adding X amount, So I was getting OTP message from **SBI** but in the next transaction when I was adding Y amount, I was getting OTP message from **BHIM SBI Pay**.

What could be the reasons behind it?
Is it becuase of the payment gateway (Like PayU,CC Avenue) or somethineg else?
Has anyone else observed the OTP message coming in the name of **BHIM SBI Pay / SBIPAY**?
[image: AD-SBIPAY]

[image: TM-SBIOTP]

Answer (score 2):

It's typical that a single server can't handle the workload of a big service, but there must be a cluster of servers. As *Bharat Interface for Money* BHIM is a service by the *National Payments Corporation of India* (NPCI) and the population of India is ~18% of the total world population, that's likely the case. What you witness here is just **two SMS gateways with a slightly different configuration**.

Although confusing, this isn't really a security problem, as the payment system is feeding you with the OTP information instead of asking anything from you. Spoofing SMS messages with fake *Sender ID*s is possible i.e. either of the names you see here can't ultimately be trusted. However, receiving incorrect OTP codes wouldn't be a security risk, as it wouldn't give anyone else access to your account.